# individual if statem. ok, multiple similar if statem. in for loop produces NA's

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

i wrote a function where the individual if statements execute ok.
If I place them in a for loop I get NA's as a result. I can't find my error.

Total data:

```
structure(list(ID = c("ClearHelder", "Donkerblauw", "Donkerbruin", "Donkergeel", "Donkergroen", "Donkeroranje", "Donkerroodpaars", "Lichtblauw", "Lichtbruin", "Lichtekleur", "Lichtgroenturq", "Opakblauw", "Opakgeel", "Opakoranje", "Opakrood", "Witopak"), 
L = c(58.8333333333333, 32.26, 28.9433333333333, 63.9566666666667, 
37.1666666666667, 49.57, 29.0433333333333, 45.7266666666667, 
32.045, 51.3516666666667, 45.8533333333333, 42.6733333333333, 
73.3333333333333, 55.7066666666667, 39.5333333333333, 83.64
), a = c(-2.25666666666667, -0.326666666666667, 5.14, -7.44666666666667, 
-23.68, 27.5033333333333, 31.38, -5.71, 5.41, 5.63666666666667, 
-22.5466666666667, -15.7466666666667, 7.52333333333333, 34.0666666666667, 
38.4266666666667, -1.25666666666667), b = c(1.07, -20, 14.8433333333333, 
64.1666666666667, 14.5466666666667, 44.0266666666667, 10.8133333333333, 
-15.27, 14.105, 24.02, 2.78666666666667, -31.03, 46.96, 51.0266666666667, 
21.3033333333333, 1.33333333333333), DE = c(58.8833333333333, 
37.9733333333333, 32.9333333333333, 90.9133333333333, 46.5033333333333, 
71.7866666666667, 44.11, 48.5466666666667, 35.43, 56.9966666666667, 
51.1833333333333, 55.07, 87.4166666666667, 82.9066666666667, 
57.3033333333333, 83.66), heightmm = c(17.6666666666667, 
18.6666666666667, 21.6666666666667, 14.3333333333333, 10.3333333333333, 
9.66666666666667, 16, 23.6666666666667, 7.5, 19.1666666666667, 
8.33333333333333, 11.3333333333333, 8.66666666666667, 7.33333333333333, 
8.33333333333333, 10.3333333333333), L1 = c(58.8333333333333, 
32.26, 28.9433333333333, 63.9566666666667, 37.1666666666667, 
49.57, 29.0433333333333, 45.7266666666667, 32.045, 51.3516666666667, 
45.8533333333333, 42.6733333333333, 73.3333333333333, 55.7066666666667, 
39.5333333333333, 83.64), C = c(2.5, 20.0033333333333, 15.7133333333333, 
64.6, 27.7933333333333, 51.92, 33.1866666666667, 16.3033333333333, 
15.105, 24.6966666666667, 22.7166666666667, 34.81, 47.5966666666667, 
61.26, 43.9533333333333, 1.85), h = c(154.583333333333, 269.066666666667, 
70.9, 96.62, 148.446666666667, 58.0133333333333, 18.8433333333333, 
249.483333333333, 68.98, 76.6866666666667, 172.963333333333, 
243.093333333333, 80.8866666666667, 52.8766666666667, 28.93, 
134.26), SDL = c(1.6015721442799, 1.87128298234126, 0.697877735232563, 
0.759561276878521, 2.73075691582633, 0.624259561400543, 0.820751687986892, 
1.50230933343747, 0.431335136523796, 0.765569504791475, 1.64536723357837, 
1.47869311668559, 2.45528681284556, 2.88377067974091, 5.43927691272777, 
0.618789140176196), SDa = c(0.0838649708360607, 0.106926766215636, 
0.17, 0.632639971337042, 0.45639894828976, 1.34001243775322, 
0.946202938063499, 0.112694276695846, 0.15556349186104, 0.986279203200933, 
0.680024509362224, 1.07342132144528, 0.257164020293145, 0.734325086956269, 
1.78146943092868, 0.098657657246325), SDb = c(0.0916515138991168, 
0.288444102037118, 0.583209510667764, 2.22554113269859, 0.673523075575985, 
0.88793768550126, 0.492172056636024, 0.281602556806575, 0.615182899632296, 
1.85564005130305, 0.328075194632775, 0.515072810387036, 1.87032082809341, 
3.61903762529948, 2.51213720432092, 0.408697116864474), SDDE = c(1.60157214427991, 
1.47585003754898, 0.575354962899719, 1.63469670989249, 1.77128013971063, 
0.895786432880808, 0.626019169035583, 1.50274193836911, 0.169705627484768, 
1.07548438699345, 1.37485756838057, 1.2285357137666, 1.78421784918023, 
3.21324342889444, 0.828090172223613, 0.625539766921335), 
SDheightmm = c(1.15470053837925, 1.52752523165195, 0.577350269189626, 
1.52752523165195, 1.15470053837925, 0.577350269189626, 1, 
0.577350269189626, 0.707106781186548, 3.7638632635454, 0.577350269189626, 
1.52752523165195, 1.15470053837925, 1.52752523165195, 1.52752523165195, 
0.577350269189626), SDL1 = c(1.6015721442799, 1.87128298234126, 
0.697877735232563, 0.759561276878521, 2.73075691582633, 0.624259561400543, 
0.820751687986892, 1.50230933343747, 0.431335136523796, 0.765569504791475, 
1.64536723357837, 1.47869311668559, 2.45528681284556, 2.88377067974091, 
5.43927691272777, 0.618789140176196), SDC = c(0.0360555127546398, 
0.282901631902915, 0.601775151807828, 2.2400669632848, 0.739346558342793, 
1.07670794554512, 1.04987300819353, 0.277908857961263, 0.51618795026618, 
1.7203681776488, 0.70528953865298, 0.155241746962601, 1.85564903290825, 
2.94001700675353, 2.7588463772623, 0.253574446662119), SDh = c(2.65108154030262, 
0.326547597347358, 0.339558536926997, 0.511175116765277, 
0.716961179795206, 1.32666247905537, 0.545007645206316, 0.429224106188516, 
1.3717871555019, 2.84698905278308, 0.673968347426892, 1.94448793602155, 
0.659191423892431, 4.27468517359271, 1.82189461824772, 10.3321198212177
), hex = c("#8A8F8C", "#354E6B", "#54412E", "#AC9C14", "#34613F", 
"#B0622A", "#732E35", "#507085", "#5B4836", "#917652", "#3F7767", 
"#466889", "#DBAD5D", "#CC6B2B", "#9C3F3D", "#CFD1CE")), .Names = c("ID", "L", "a", "b", "DE", "heightmm", "L1", "C", "h", "SDL", "SDa", "SDb", "SDDE", "SDheightmm", "SDL1", "SDC", "SDh", "hex"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Trun data:

```
structure(list(Sample = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Sample 1", "Sample 2", "Sample 3", "Sample 4", "Sample 5", "Sample 6"), class = "factor"), 
Time = structure(1:6, .Label = c("10:51:04 AM", "10:51:05 AM", 
"10:51:06 AM", "10:51:07 AM", "10:51:08 AM", "10:51:09 AM"
), class = "factor"), L = c(57.61, 57.16, 53.96, 57.3, 55.27, 
57.9), C = c(4.56, 4.17, 5.14, 3.9, 3.63, 3.47), h = c(219.98, 
226.13, 233.39, 221.78, 213.56, 214.16), L1 = c(57.61, 57.16, 
53.96, 57.3, 55.27, 57.9), a = c(-3.49, -2.89, -3.06, -2.91, 
-3.03, -2.87), b = c(-2.93, -3.01, -4.13, -2.6, -2.01, -1.95
), DE = c(36.52, 36.95, 40.24, 36.78, 38.77, 36.13), heihgtmm = c(53.1, 
67.01, 80.16, 85.3, 86.37, 92.36), hex = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA)), .Names = c("Sample", "Time", "L", "C", "h", "L1", "a", "b", "DE", "heihgtmm", "hex"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

The code for one line execution:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(Trun)){
 if (Trun$L[i] > Total$L[1]-Total$SDL[1] & Trun$L[i] < Total$L[1]+Total$SDL[1]){
 Trun$hex[i] <- Total$hex[1]
}}
```

This gives the right result:

```
Sample        Time     L     C    h      L1     a     b    DE   heihgtmm     hex
1 Sample 1 10:51:04 AM 57.61 4.56 219.98 57.61 -3.49 -2,93 36.52    53.10 #8A8F8C
2 Sample 2 10:51:05 AM 57.16 4.17 226.13 57.16 -2.89 -3,01 36.95    67.01    <NA>
3 Sample 3 10:51:06 AM 53.96 5.14 233.39 53.96 -3.06 -4,13 40.24    80.16    <NA>
4 Sample 4 10:51:07 AM 57.30 3.90 221.78 57.30 -2.91  -2,6 36.78    85.30 #8A8F8C
5 Sample 5 10:51:08 AM 55.27 3.63 213.56 55.27 -3.03 -2,01 38.77    86.37    <NA>
6 Sample 6 10:51:09 AM 57.90 3.47 214.16 57.90 -2.87 -1,95 36.13    92.36 #8A8F8C
```

Making a function with multiple similar statements in a variable:

```
colortest <- function(x){
for ( i in 1:nrow(x)){
    if (x$L[i] > Total$L[1]-Total$SDL[1] & x$L[i] < Total$L[1]+Total$SDL[1]){
        x$hex[i] <- Total$hex[1]
    }else if(x$L[i] > Total$L[2]-Total$SDL[2] & x$L[i] < Total$L[2]+Total$SDL[2]){
        x$hex[i] <- Total$hex[2]
    }else if (x$L[i] > Total$L[3]-Total$SDL[3] & x$L[i] < Total$L[3]+Total$SDL[3]){
        x$hex[i] <- Total$hex[3]
    }else if (x$L[i] > Total$L[4]-Total$SDL[4] & x$L[i] < Total$L[4]+Total$SDL[4]){
        x$hex[i] <- Total$hex[4]
    }else if (x$L[i] > Total$L[5]-Total$SDL[5] & x$L[i] < Total$L[5]+Total$SDL[5]){
        x$hex[i] <- Total$hex[5]
    }else if (x$L[i] > Total$L[6]-Total$SDL[6] & x$L[i] < Total$L[6]+Total$SDL[6]){
        x$hex[i] <- Total$hex[6]
    }else if (x$L[i] > Total$L[7]-Total$SDL[7] & x$L[i] < Total$L[7]+Total$SDL[7]){
        x$hex[i] <- Total$hex[7]
    }else if (x$L[i] > Total$L[8]-Total$SDL[8] & x$L[i] < Total$L[8]+Total$SDL[8]){
        x$hex[i] <- Total$hex[8]
    }else if (x$L[i] > Total$L[9]-Total$SDL[9] & x$L[i] < Total$L[9]+Total$SDL[9]){
        x$hex[i] <- Total$hex[9]
    }else if (x$L[i] > Total$L[10]-Total$SDL[10] & x$L[i] < Total$L[10]+Total$SDL[10]){
        x$hex[i] <- Total$hex[10]
    }else if (x$L[i] > Total$L[11]-Total$SDL[11] & x$L[i] < Total$L[11]+Total$SDL[11]){
        x$hex[i] <- Total$hex[11]
    }else if (x$L[i] > Total$L[12]-Total$SDL[12] & x$L[i] < Total$L[12]+Total$SDL[12]){
        x$hex[i] <- Total$hex[12]
    }else if (x$L[i] > Total$L[13]-Total$SDL[13] & x$L[i] < Total$L[13]+Total$SDL[13]){
        x$hex[i] <- Total$hex[13]
    }else if (x$L[i] > Total$L[14]-Total$SDL[14] & x$L[i] < Total$L[14]+Total$SDL[14]){
        x$hex[i] <- Total$hex[14]
    }else if (x$L[i] > Total$L[15]-Total$SDL[15] & x$L[i] < Total$L[15]+Total$SDL[15]){
        x$hex[i] <- Total$hex[15]
    }else if (x$L[i] > Total$L[16]-Total$SDL[16] & x$L[i] < Total$L[16]+Total$SDL[16]){
        x$hex[i] <- Total$hex[16]
    }
}}
```

execute colortest(Trun) gives the result with the NA's:

```
Sample        Time     L     C    h      L1    a      b    DE    heihgtmm  hex
1 Sample 1 10:51:04 AM 57.61 4.56 219.98 57.61 -3.49 -2,93 36.52    53.10 <NA>
2 Sample 2 10:51:05 AM 57.16 4.17 226.13 57.16 -2.89 -3,01 36.95    67.01 <NA>
3 Sample 3 10:51:06 AM 53.96 5.14 233.39 53.96 -3.06 -4,13 40.24    80.16 <NA>
4 Sample 4 10:51:07 AM 57.30 3.90 221.78 57.30 -2.91  -2,6 36.78    85.30 <NA>
5 Sample 5 10:51:08 AM 55.27 3.63 213.56 55.27 -3.03 -2,01 38.77    86.37 <NA>
6 Sample 6 10:51:09 AM 57.90 3.47 214.16 57.90 -2.87 -1,95 36.13    92.36 <NA>
```

What must I change in the function to make the if lines work just like the individual example?

Comment: trun and total have necessarily the same number of row, correct?

Comment: Can you `dput` the two data frames so we can reproduce this?

Comment: Colonel, Trun and Total don't have the same number of rows.
Total is a reference to fill Trun (testrun) data with. Trun is actually 1000 lines but I thought posting the head would be fine.

Comment: Josh, I'm not that familiar with dput yet. Is this adjustment what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a much less verbose way of doing what you're trying to do. Firstly, it's worth noting that some of your intervals overlap, but I'm assuming that as per your code that you want the first matching entry from `Total`.

```
library("matrixStats")
check_element <- function(i, L) {
  abs(L - Total$L[i]) < Total$SDL[i] | NA
}
# returns TRUE for L within range or NA if not
matched_matrix <- outer(1:nrow(Total), Trun$L, check_element) *
  1:nrow(Total)
matched_item <- colMins(matched_matrix, na.rm = TRUE)
Trun$hex <- Total$hex[matched_item]
```

Comment: Thank you nick, I hope that less verbose work will come with experience.
I will look into your code.
The overlap of intervals is part of the measurements. Eventually the code would not only check for the L value but also C, h, a, b and DE intervals before assigning a hex number form the reference table (Total)

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't return properly.

```
...
    }else if (x$L[i] > Total$L[16]-Total$SDL[16] & x$L[i] < Total$L[16]+Total$SDL[16]){
        x$hex[i] <- Total$hex[16]
    }
}
return(x)
}
```